# How to "grep" in PowerShell and also show surrounding lines/context?

Tags: powershell, cmd, command, full-text-search, command-line-arguments

What are the "Context Line Control" settings of the Powershell cmd: findstr or what is an alternative Powershell cmd which will let me find a string in some output and also give me the convenience to print surrounding lines?

On GNU/Linux I would do: `grep -A 5 -B 5 somestring file.txt`

The command below searches for the string "four" but asks grep to show 1 line above the found line and 2 lines below the found line which has the string present.

```
$ grep -A 2 -B 1 four tmp.text
three
four
five
six
$ cat tmp.text
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
```

Thanks

Comment: I added a sample to illustrate what I am looking for.

Comment: Take a look at [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String?view=powershell-7). You should read the complete help including the examples to learn hot to use it.

Comment: I like how you answered it the moment after he had the answer posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an answer here: https://communary.net/2014/11/10/grep-the-powershell-way/

You can search the example file like:

```
PS C:\Users\dan> Select-String four .\tmp.txt -Context 1,3

  tmp.txt:3:three
> tmp.txt:4:four
  tmp.txt:5:five
  tmp.txt:6:six
  tmp.txt:7:seven
```

Comment: You can also use the actual bash command you demonstrated in your question with `bash -c "grep -A 2 -B 1 four tmp.text"`

Comment: Nice, yeah by using WSL(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).